# Upload error 500 when using flash to upload

Tags: php, flash, file-upload, upload

I've been trying to configure uploading and I've been getting an error 500.

I'm running a server on Apache2 with php5+ installed. I'm curious to why i keep getting an error.

I added these commands to try to fix it, nothing has worked yet.

```
  <IfModule mod_security.c>
    secfilterengine off
   secfilterscanPOST off
</IfModule>

<ifmodule mod_php5.c>
 php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
 php_value post_max_size 1000M
</ifmodule>
```

I looked at another solution but i don't know the module command for it,

SecRuleEngine Off
SecRequestBodyAccess Off

NOTE: I added those to my .htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a 500 should put something useful in your /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: I'll take a look at it and let you know in under 5 minutes

Comment: Okay it says I'm exceeding the maximum amount of bytes required. I'm going to test to see if that fixed it, I changed php.ini in apache2 and also php.ini in /php5/cli/

Comment: I no longer get the error 500 message, my webpage becomes unresponsive when it beings to convert videos.